# I am looking for a research paper on the $M$ parameter

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I'm looking for a research paper on the $M$ parameter, bicyclic units of $\mathbb ZS_3$. Can anyone help me? I have found it in *Bull. Belg. Math. Soc.* 1992. Can anybody tell me where it can be acessed?

> Jespers, E.; Parmenter, M. M.; Bicyclic units in ZS3. *Bull. Soc. Math. Belg.* Sér. B 44 (1992), no. 2, 141–146. [MR1313860](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1313860)

Comment: Are you sure it is from 1992? From what I see, volume 1 of this journal dates from 1994.

Comment: In the past, there were some questions on locating some papers which is difficult to access. But you should add complete reference. (You probably know at least author's name and the title.)

Comment: Eric Jespers and M.M.Parmenter, bicyclic units of ZS3

Comment: yes mm sure it is from 1992

Comment: Project Euclid only has this from 1994: http://projecteuclid.org/all/euclid.bbms.

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot find this journal in a library near you (I cannot find it online, neither free nor in paid access), try contacting the authors and ask them for an electronic copy - most scientists will be happy to provide you with one. In order to avoid spamming them, I shall not post the authors' email addresses here, but you can find Parmenter [here](http://www.mun.ca/people_departments/index.php?action=mainPageSearch&query=parmenter&viewEmail=1&userID=3692) (I think he is retired) and Jespers [here](http://homepages.vub.ac.be/~efjesper/).